# Format WeekDays range in column to separate Weekdays column

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame is having Time column. which has data like

```
['Mon-Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sun', 'Tue-Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun', 'Mon-Thu', 'Sun', 'Fri-Sun', nan, 'Tue',
   'Mon, Wed', 'Mon-Fri', 'Mon', 'Mon-Sat',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Sat-Sun', 'Wed-Sun', 'Mon-Wed', 'Mon, Tue, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Fri',
   'Tue-Sat', 'Sat', 'Mon, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri',
   'Mon, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Thu', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu, Sun', 'Fri', 'Mon-Tue', 'Thu-Sun', 'Tue-Fri',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri', 'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat', 'Wed',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sat', 'Fri-Sat', 'Mon, Wed, Thu',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Tue-Thu',
   'Mon, Tue, Sun', 'Mon, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Sat', 'Thu-Sat',
   'Mon, Sat, Sun', 'Thu', 'Mon, Fri', 'Tue, Sat, Sun', 'Wed-Sat',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Sat', 'Mon, Thu, Sat',
   'Mon, Thu, Fri', 'Mon, Fri, Sat', 'Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun']
```

Need to create additional columns in the DataFrame i.e Mon,Tue,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,Sun and insert 1 or 0 against each of these columns if the reference TIME column as the Weekday in it.

I have created the said columns

Expected Results

```
TIME.                         Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri Sat Sun.     

Mon-Sun.                      1. 1.   1.   1.   1.  1.  1
Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun. 1. 1.   0    1    1.  1   1
```

Comment: Are you going to have things like: `Mon-Wed, Fri, Sun` or `Mon-Thu, Fri-Sat, Sun` ?

Comment: Nope it would either be 'Mon-Wed' like ranges or individual 'Mon,Tue,Thu'

Comment: So... `Mon-Wed, Fri-Sat` would be possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['Mon-Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sun', 'Tue-Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun', 'Mon-Thu', 'Sun', 'Fri-Sun', None, 'Tue',
   'Mon, Wed', 'Mon-Fri', 'Mon', 'Mon-Sat',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Sat-Sun', 'Wed-Sun', 'Mon-Wed', 'Mon, Tue, Fri, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Fri',
   'Tue-Sat', 'Sat', 'Mon, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri',
   'Mon, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Thu', 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu, Sun', 'Fri', 'Mon-Tue', 'Thu-Sun', 'Tue-Fri',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Sun', 'Mon, Tue, Sat, Sun',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Sun',
   'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri', 'Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat', 'Wed',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sat', 'Fri-Sat', 'Mon, Wed, Thu',
   'Mon, Tue, Wed, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Tue-Thu',
   'Mon, Tue, Sun', 'Mon, Fri, Sat, Sun', 'Mon, Sat', 'Thu-Sat',
   'Mon, Sat, Sun', 'Thu', 'Mon, Fri', 'Tue, Sat, Sun', 'Wed-Sat',
   'Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat', 'Mon, Wed, Thu, Sat', 'Mon, Thu, Sat',
   'Mon, Thu, Fri', 'Mon, Fri, Sat', 'Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun']
```

```
import pandas as pd

header = ['TIME.', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
result = []

for week in data:
    result_row = [week] + [0]*7
    if week is not None:
        week = week.replace(" ", "")
        for entry in week.split(','): 
            if len(entry.split('-'))>1:
                start_idx = header.index(entry.split('-')[0])
                end_idx = header.index(entry.split('-')[1])+1
                for i in range(start_idx, end_idx):
                    result_row[i] = 1
            else:
                idx = header.index(entry)
                result_row[idx] = 1
    result.append(result_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=header)
```

```
print(df)

                           TIME.  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun
0                        Mon-Sun    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1   Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
2   Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sun    1    1    1    1    1    0    1
3                        Tue-Sun    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
4        Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
5                        Mon-Thu    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
6                            Sun    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
7                        Fri-Sun    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
8                           None    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
9                            Tue    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
10                      Mon, Wed    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
11                       Mon-Fri    1    1    1    1    1    0    0
12                           Mon    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
13                       Mon-Sat    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
14  Mon, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun    1    0    1    1    1    1    1
15  Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
16                       Sat-Sun    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
...
```